# Variable Not Rendering with ng-bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a sample app from the book, [AngularJS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449344852).

In the following code, `{{funding.needed}}` doesn't show up as `10 * startingEstimate`. It shows up literally, i.e. not rendered, as `{{funding.needed}}` on the page.

Why?

```
<html ng-app>
<body ng-controller="TextController">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js">
      </script>

    <form ng-controller="StartUpController">
        Starting: <input ng-change="computeNeeded()"
                         ng-model="funding.startingEstimate">
        Recommendation: {{funding.needed}}
    </form>

    <script>
        function StartUpController($scope) {
            $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0};

            $scope.computeNeeded = function() { 
                $scope.needed = $scope.startingEstimate * 10;
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the TextController as you have not defined this and it's blocking loading other things as it errors. Also you'll need to normalize your use of the $scope.funding object in some places you try to use just the members without the parent reference. The following is a working version (see it working on the plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/Jz95UlOakKLJIqHvkXlp?p=preview)

```
<html ng-app>
<body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js">
      </script>

    <form ng-controller="StartUpController">
        Starting: <input ng-change="computeNeeded()"
                         ng-model="funding.startingEstimate">
        Recommendation: {{funding.needed}}
    </form>

    <script>
        function StartUpController($scope) {
            $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0};

            $scope.computeNeeded = function() { 
                $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```